# Split string and append to array

Tags: ruby, string, split, concatenation

I would like to split a string and append the split result to two separate arrays simultaneously. Is there a way to do this? For example:

```
mystrings = ['abc:def', 'ghi:jkl', 'mno:pqr']
first = []
second = []
mystrings.each do |string|
  first, second << string.split(':')
end
```

This doesn't work. But I didn't know if there was a syntactical Ruby way to perform the split and appending simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mystrings = ['abc:def', 'ghi:jkl', 'mno:pqr']
first, second = mystrings.map{|str| str.split(":")}.transpose
```